# Java - generalizing method - "Class" instance used for type parameter

Tags: java

I have a couple of method for serializing different classes, let's say A, B and C.

They look like this (for each class):

```
public byte[] serializeData(A object) throws IOException {
...
        FieldSerializer<?> serializer = new FieldSerializer<A>(kryo, A.class);
        kryo.register(A.class, serializer);
...
}
```

I would like to generalize those methods somehow to avoid code duplication.

First I thought about parametrizing this method but that wouldn't work because of type erasure - I still need "A.class" to pass as an argument.

Then I thought about passing in addition an instance of "Class" so that it can be used as a second argument to FieldSerializer and parametrizing the method:

```
public <T> byte[] serializeData(T object, Class clazz) throws IOException{
...
        FieldSerializer<?> serializer = new FieldSerializer<T>(kryo, clazz);
        kryo.register(clazz, serializer);
...
}
```

but then it still doesn't look right. Is there anyway to make it more neat? Ideally I would like to have either a parametrized method or passing the Class instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Object.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29):

```
public byte[] serializeData(T object) throws IOException {
    ...
    FieldSerializer<?> serializer = new FieldSerializer<T>(kryo, object.getClass());
    kryo.register(object.getClass(), serializer);
    ...
}
```